# How to allow dots in Slim 3 or nikic/FastRoute parameters?

Tags: php, url-routing, slim, slim-3

I am using Slim 3, which uses nikic/FastRoute, and am having trouble with an endpoint like so:

```
$app->get('/count/{url}', function ($request, $response) use ($curl) {
    $controller = new Proximate\Controller\CountUrl($request, $response);
    $controller->setCurl($curl);
    return $controller->execute();
});
```

My plan is to pass an urlencoded URL into `{url}` and inject that into the controller. For example, for `http://www.example.com`, the request would be:

```
curl \
    --verbose \
    http://localhost:8080/count/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F
```

However, this fails with a 404, so is evidently not matched. This also fails:

```
curl \
    --verbose \
    http://localhost:8080/count/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.
```

However, oddly, this does match (i.e. without the trailing dot):

```
curl \
    --verbose \
    http://localhost:8080/count/http%3A%2F%2Fwww
```

I originally thought it was the urlencoded slashes that was confusing it (`%2F`) but having tried it without these characters, I find that in fact it is the dot, anywhere in the string. Why does this not match, and do I need a regex match in order to get this to work?

I am using the PHP built-in web server for this app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit more digging, I find that this is caused by the PHP built-in web server, and is not a Slim or FastRoute issue at all. Here is [the Slim bug report](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/359) and here is one [for PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61286).

Sadly the core PHP team have marked as `Won't fix`, since the server is only for testing. Personally, I think the warnings about not using this server for production are a bit overblown (my Docker containers remain of a  reasonably manageable size *because* I am not throwing Apache in there as well).

Thankfully there is a fix for this - specifying the script name in the URL will cause PHP to pass the rest of it correctly to the routing system. Like so:

```
curl \
    --verbose \
    http://localhost:8080/index.php/count/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F
#                         ^^^^^^^^^
#                         Script name
```

Of course, this is not very elegant, so I may yet switch to another solution. I've not tried it yet, but [this PHP-only web server](https://github.com/appserver-io/webserver) looks quite promising.